# Compare file in Hadoop - Custom PIG loader

Tags: file, hadoop, apache-pig

I want to write a custom PIG loader to load records from a multiline format to single line format. Later i want to compare each sub records. 
How to write something like this ?

Here is the file format - Input

```
File : 
REC|**Record_1**|ABC|DEF|GEH|1234
SUB_REC1|111|222|333|444|5555
SUB_REC1|AAA|BBB|CCC|DDD
SUB_REC2|EEE|FFF|GGG|HHH
SUB_REC2|III|JJJ
REC|**Record_2**|XYZ|MNO|PQR|1234
SUB_REC1|111|222|333|444|5555
SUB_REC1|AAA|BBB|CCC|DDD
SUB_REC2|EEE|FFF|GGG|HHH
SUB_REC2|III|JJJ
```

Expected output :

```
**Record_1**:REC|**Record_1**|ABC|DEF|GEH|1234~SUB_REC1|111|222|333|444|5555~SUB_REC1|AAA|BBB|CCC|DDD~SUB_REC2|EEE|FFF|GGG|HHH~SUB_REC2|III|JJJ
**Record_2**:REC|**Record_2**|XYZ|MNO|PQR|1234~SUB_REC1|111|222|333|444|5555~SUB_REC1|AAA|BBB|CCC|DDD~SUB_REC2|EEE|FFF|GGG|HHH~SUB_REC2|III|JJJ
```

Comment: Yes PIG is one of the better way you can do it.HIVE would cause lot of overhead because of joins.

Comment: @aviral tell me more how Pig can do MapReduce without any joins

Comment: I am not sure I got your question Thomas. Pig performs MapReduce in any case. What are you trying to say in terms of joins?

Comment: So you start a question about Hadoop to switch it later to Pig?